# docker-compose does not attach stdin to .net core app Console.ReadLine

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I've noticed strange behavior when using `docker-compose`.
`Console.ReadLine()` does not wait for user-input.

Observe the following simplified dot net core c# console app:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input something:");
    while (true)
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Input was: {line}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If you run this via `docker run -i readline` **it works fine**:

[image]

But if you use `docker-compose up` it just loops without waiting for input on STDIN:

[image]

Why is that?

You can try it yourself using:

```
git clone https://github.com/mh-qUjB/docker-dotnetcore-readline.git
cd ./docker-dotnetcore-readline/ReadLine
docker-compose up
```

I'm currently testing this on:

- `Ubuntu 16.04`
- `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`
- `docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe`
- `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`
- Dockerfile see [here](https://github.com/mh-qUjB/docker-dotnetcore-readline/blob/master/ReadLine/Dockerfile)

Thank you.

PS: if you could improve the title of this question I'd be happy.

Comment: docker-compose is one direction : container to host, you can't do user input directly using docker-compose.

Comment: You might try `docker-compose up -d` waiting for the container to start and then attaching directly with `docker attach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find individual container and execute the command in that container. Docker compose is streaming your logs, because of this it does not provide you an interactive shell.

As example lets say you have this compose file,

```js
version: '3'

services:
  nats:
    image: nats-streaming
  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

You can execute command in each container like bellow

```
docker-compose exec mongo sh
docker-compose exec nats sh
```